# Pure CSS Selected Tab On Load Behavior

Tags: css, menu, tabs

I found this CSS Menu Tabs on the internet and it works great without any scripts. Unfortunately is has 2 issues. The first issue is that when page loads it displays the contents of the last tab. I was able to cheat this by creating a duplicate of tab 1. The second issue that I can’t solve is having tab 1 highlighted when page first loads as selected tab. I can style tab 1 to be highlighted when page loads but I can’t figure out how to un-highlight it when another tab is selected. Could anyone please help or at least tell me if it’s possible in CSS?

CSS

```
`.w3c {
    min-height:250px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.w3c > div {
}
.w3c > div > a {
    margin-left:6px;
    position:relative;
    left:1px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-top:1px solid #cbcbcb;
    border-left:1px solid #cbcbcb;
    border-right:1px solid #cbcbcb;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
}
.w3c > div:not(:target) > a {
    border-bottom:0px;
    background-image:url(Example%20Six_files/Untitled-4.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.w3c > div:target > a {
    background:#FFF;
    color:#000000;
}
.w3c > div > div {
    background:#FFF;
    z-index:-2;
    left:0px;
    top:24px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    padding:20px;
}
.w3c > div:not(:target) > div {
    position:absolute;
}
.w3c > div:target > div {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}
.w3c div a:hover {
    background:#FFF;
    color:#000000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
}`
```

HTML

```
`<div style="width:960px; border:solid 1px #cbcbcb; border-radius:5px; background-image:url(Example%20Six_files/Untitled-3.png); background-repeat:repeat-x;">
  <div class="w3c" style="margin-top:6px;">
    <div id="tab01">
      <a href="#tab01" style="margin-left:13px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">Overview</a>
      <div>
        Overview
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab02">
      <a href="#tab02" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">Product Details</a>
      <div>
        Product Details
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab03">
      <a href="#tab03" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">Specifications</a>
      <div>
        Specifications
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab04">
      <a href="#tab04" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">Manufacturer</a>
      <div>
        Manufacturer
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab05">
      <a href="#tab05" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">Accessories</a>
      <div>
        Accessories
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a style="display:none;"></a>
      <div>
        Overview
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a script since IE doesn't support the :target selector. This way you can also decide which tab you want selected when the page loads.